# C# Windows-Form Excel Database Pull

Tags: c#, excel, database, visual-studio, user-interface

Ok, so I have a very big/complicated question so bear with me. I am writing a software for a company. It is basically going to run as a GUI for their database that is in Excel. I am running into a problem that I personally have no idea how to get around. I have a windows form that has textboxes that the worker will fill out that will form a daily report for the company. I attach a printer of my form below. What I the program to do is, when the person enters the phase number, and then select weld or flange, I need the code to go into my excel spread sheet and pull all of the weld of flange numbers(whichever was selected in the second box) and put them into either an autocomplete or drop down list in the third box. Basically this will dummy proof the companies report making by not allowing room for human error with manual entry. I also attached a picture of my excel database so you can see how it works. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this.
[Daily Report Form GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0rWa.png)    --- [Excel Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztgTI.png)

```
 private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string phasetocheck = textBox1.Text;
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        string cells = Form1.filePath;
        Excel ex = new Excel(cells, 1);
        string[,] phasenumbers = ex.ReadRange(2, 2, 57400, 4);
        int j = 0;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();


        int i = 2;

        foreach (string x in phasenumbers)
        {
            if(phasetocheck.Contains(x))
            {
                list.Add(phasenumbers[4, j]);
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        string[] weldnums = list.ToArray();

        textBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(weldnums);
```

Comment: Post your code, and we will try to help you with the issues.  Just on a side note: Excel is a spreadsheet, not a database.

Comment: I realize it is not a database, however this company uses it to keep track with their records.

Comment: Is it possible they will change the Excel while your program is running? If not, I would recommend using ADO.Net and querying the sheets as if they were tables in a database, which is a lot easier.

Comment: @NetMage no the Excel files are static. How does ado.net work?

Comment: I added an answer with sample code. It does require installing software on the client PC from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of using ADO.Net to access an Excel Database. You need to have Access or the Access runtime engine (I believe I use MS Access Database Engine 2010 with 32-bit .Net - should also be possible to use with 64-bit).

```
const string provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
const string filePath = @"C:\temp";
const string filenameTemplate = "*DataFile.xlsx";
string filename = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, filenameTemplate).First();

var cn = new OleDbConnection($"Provider={provider};Data Source={filename};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'");
cn.Open();

var cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = cn;

var SheetName = "[ALL USERS WITH ACCESS$]";

cmd.CommandText = $"select * from {SheetName}";

var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
var dt = new DataTable();

da.Fill(dt);
```